# Result of combination of Ctrl+c and then Ctrl+z in shell

Tags: shell, job-control

Which signal will be sent to the running process after sending the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> after 500ms of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>?

I have tried to give the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> but I didn't get the exact answers for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will send SIGINT to the foreground process group.

As you have backgrounded the process beforehand by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't give you the desired result expectedly.

Comment: SO, what happens in the vice-versa scenario?

Comment: @preeti If the foreground program does not have any handler for SIGINT, the program will be killed in response to Ctrl+C..so Ctrl+Z won't affect that program (As it is killed already), it would affect the foreground process group at the instant of pressing Ctrl+Z..

Answer (score 0):

heemayl is right, let us do an experiment

```
ping google.com
```

Ping is running. When you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> it will send process to background but that process is still running you can check it using `bg`.

So as we know this process is in backgroud how can <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> can know about it ?
So it will stop working.

Comment: This looks moire like a comment/question than an answer.

Comment: i can not add comment less reputation